# Material Utilities add-on not working

Tags: materials, add-on

I would like to use the Material Utilities add-on for the first time, but I cannot get it to work as described here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/addons/materials/material_utils.html.

Situation:

- Material Utilities 2.2.0 is enabled in Add-on Preferences;
- Invoking Shift-Q from the 3D Viewport does nothing;
- Documentation says Material Utilities can also be accessed via "Properties > Materials > Specials", but where is "Properties"? I have no idea what that is.

Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.4, Windows 11

**UPDATE:** Never mind, I figured it out. You need to have the Shader Editor open for Shift-Q to work, something the documentation appears to fail to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Properties* is one of the main editors (windows like *3D Viewport*, *Outliner* etc...) you have in Blender. By default it's in the bottom right corner, I'm sure you've seen it before:

[image]

When the add-on is enabled, the Specials menu is located to the right of the material slots box, with a downwards caret button. This provides the same options you get with the <kbd>Shift + Q</kbd> shortcut.

> Never mind, I figured it out. You need to have the Shader Editor open for Shift-Q to work, something the documentation appears to fail to mention.

This is not true, it should be available in 3D Viewport as well. If the shortcut is not working there, it's possibly due to a hotkey conflict. In *Preferences > Keymap*, you can search for "shift q" in the *Key Binding* mode or for "material utilities" in *Name* mode to check to see if there are more than one operators assigned to that same shortcut. A normal, working setup is highlighted with green in the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Very much appreciated. I filter add-ons by workspace and it turned out I had filtered out Material Utilities in all but my Shader workspace. 

Thanks for the tip regarding Properties. If I understand correctly, when the documentation referred to Properties, technically it was referring to Material Properties. Thanks again!

Comment: @WilburPost Not quite. That whole window (or "editor" to be exact) is the Properties Editor: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/properties_editor.html The vertical column of icons in that Properties window are each a "(Something) Properties" tab. Material Properties is one of them: https://i.imgur.com/HOnUzP2.png